# Unable to import certain files

Tags: python

I'm experiencing an odd error where certain modules can't be imported.  When attempting to import them, I get this error.

```
RuntimeError: unable to get file status from '/path/to/file.py'
```

So far, all of these unimportable modules are located on a network drive, but other modules also located on the network drive *are* importable, and so far I've not been able to find a difference between the ones that are and are not importable.  All of these modules were working until recently.

A quick search of google doesn't show any similar errors related to "file status".  Has anyone experienced this error before?

Comment: Do you have permissions to those files?

Comment: Yes, the permissions appear to be the same for importable and non-importable modules.  I can browse to and view them in windows explorer.

Comment: Could these file be in use by another program (like a text editor or IDE)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that this problem was related to the fact that the *bad* modules all had invalid file creation times (i.e. `stat.st_ctime`).  I think the problem was likely caused by some backup software that runs in linux that somehow managed to clear the file creation times.

When importing a python module, I believe it compares the creation times from the `.py` file and the `.pyc` file, if it exists, to know whether it needs to re-compile a `.pyc`.  In this case, it was breaking when it couldn't find a file creation time for the file.

I made a script that walked through the entire directory tree, reading, deleting, then overwriting every `.py` file to force a creation time.  After that, everything seemed to work as normal again.